# clean way to make the "confirm" conditional in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I have a link_to on my rails4 page which uses slim syntax. The following link_to

```
link_to exports_path, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

is now required to only show the confirm message upon a certain condition. How do we make this happen in rails4?

I tried:

```
link_to exports_path, data: { confirm: result_count > 50 ? "Are you sure?" : nil }
```

which seems to always show the confirm regardless of the condition..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about

```
link_to exports_path, data: (result_count > 50  ?  { confirm:  "Are you sure?"} : nil)
```

Comment: Works perfectly for the one data attribute. Thanks a ton!How would this scale if there were more attributes?

Comment: data: takes a hash of any size, like  {confirm: 'really?', color: 'red', menu: 'next'} and so on

Comment: What if I want the conditional to execute on the client-side? Any clean solution for that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

you can also have the conditional for setting the confirm message or nil inside the data hash itself:

`link_to exports_path, data: { some_data: "value", confirm: result_count > 50  ?  "Are you sure?" : nil }`