# Rails UJS – conditional confirmation on client-side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

I have a `data-confirm` attribute on a button, but I only want the alert to show if a certain condition (on the client-side) is met. Does anyone know a way to do this cleanly?

I found this: [clean way to make the "confirm" conditional in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507462/clean-way-to-make-the-confirm-conditional-in-rails-4)

...but that is only for a server-side conditional.